# how to match pbo buffer with a texture?

Tags: opengl, pbo

From [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812770/copying-texture-from-gpu-to-cpu-using-pixel-buffer-objects) i know that once I bind GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, OpenGL will feed texture2D using the data in buffer bind to GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER.

But while there are various shapes of textures, such as GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_1D... there is no such a attribute of GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER's bound buffer which specifies the internal shape of its data. If I want to transfer data to a texture storage bind to GL_TEXTURE_3D using pbo, I need to first send data to the buffer bind to the pbo.

Do I need to care the data's layout I send to pbo? Like the data should be *(xxx...,yyy...,zzz...)* or *(xyz,xyz,xyz...)*.

An example or pseudocode is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using a pixel buffer in a [pixel transfer operation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) changes *one thing* about pixel transfer operations: where the data comes from. When you don't use a PBO, the data comes from (or goes to) an address in memory you directly allocated. When you do use a PBO, the data comes from (or goes to) a byte offset into a buffer object's storage.

Nothing else about the pixel transfer operation changes. How the "packed" pixel data is laid out remains the same regardless of the location of the pixel transfer.

The matters you are talking about are governed by the nature of the [pixel transfer operation you started](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_initiation) (ie: what function you called) and the [pixel transfer parameters](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_arguments) you passed to it. Again, these work the same way regardless of whether you're using a buffer object or client memory.